# How to use scala Elem produces jersey text/xml?

Tags: xml, scala, jersey

I have write a common method to generate Elem type by scala.xml lib. But Jersey use JAXB, means binding xml info with Java object. How could I simply response with scala's Elem type avoiding construct a object?

Simple Code as:

```
  @GET  
  @Path("sitemap.xml")  
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))  
  def sitemap( @Context client: DaoService[Future]) = {  
    val x: Elem = Common.defaultXml()  
    x  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a custom [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) to handle the `Elem` type. This component is what all Java object go through to serialize to the response stream. You can read more at [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). For example for `Elem` you can use something like

```
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.lang.Class
import java.lang.reflect.Type
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation

import javax.ws.rs.{ Produces }
import javax.ws.rs.core.{ MultivaluedMap, MediaType }
import javax.ws.rs.ext.{ MessageBodyWriter, Provider }

import scala.xml.Elem

@Provider
@Produces(Array("application/xml"))
class ElemWriterProvider extends MessageBodyWriter[Elem] {

  override def isWriteable(cls: Class[_], genericType: Type,
                           annotations: Array[Annotation],
                           mediaType: MediaType) = {
    classOf[Elem].isAssignableFrom(cls)
  }

  override def getSize(elem: Elem, cls: Class[_], genericType: Type,
                       annotations: Array[Annotation], mediaType: MediaType) = {
    -1L
  }

  override def writeTo(elem: Elem, cls: Class[_], genericType: Type,
                       annotations: Array[Annotation], mediaType: MediaType,
                       headers: MultivaluedMap[String, Object],
                       entityStream: OutputStream): Unit = {
    println("------- writeTo --------")
    entityStream.write(elem.buildString(false).getBytes)
  }
}
```

Then you just need to either explicitly register the writer or let it be picked up through scanning.

---

#### UPDATE

The other option (without the need for a custom provider) is to simply return the XML String ;-)

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet.The  <JAX-RS Entity Providers> is custom  and near and I have read it. Thanks the scala version.Besides, Elem.toString is a straight way to output XML.

Comment: Yeah you could avoid the needed provider altogether if you just returned the String :-)